# VSCode: Color decorators visible in jsx files and not in js files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a weird issue:

In `js` files if don't have access to the color decorators when there's a color in an attribute, but exactly the same code, if I rename the file to `.jsx` gets the color picker/decorator:

**App.js:**

[image]

**App.jsx:**

[image]

The languages are correctly detected respectively as 'javascript' and 'javascriptreact'.

The `settings.json` for that seems to be correct:

```
"[javascript][javascriptreact]": {
  "editor.colorDecorators": true
}
```

So I don't understand why javascript gets the decorators and javascriptreact doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr VS Code doesn't support this across files.

Back in 2018 they said this feature is part of the (built-in) css/html extension (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45852) and the core vscode team wasn't going to expand it.

From an issue a few months ago (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141088) they seemed to confirm the color decorators are only in CSS and JSON files, which I just verified.

I created a jsx file and couldn't get the decorator to appear for me at all. That might be a side effect of some extension you have installed. This doesn't seem to be supported by VSCode natively. On the bright side, if you can figure out which extension is making that happen, you might be able to make it work for js files too.